# GameObjects falling over when Translated in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here's the story. I have 4 gameobjects all in a row, where there right next to each other. I have a cube. When the cube collides with the gameobjects I want them to be translated, but when I begin to translate them, they start to fall over off the map. Somebody said use Kinematic on the rigid body, but when I use Kinematic (or even static) I can't collide/translate them anymore. Anyone have any solutions to this?

Here is my collision code for reference:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
Debug.Log("Collision");

if (collision.gameObject.name == "SectionOne")
{

collision.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 0, section_placement);

}
else if (collision.gameObject.name == "SectionTwo")
{

collision.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 0, section_placement);

}
else if (collision.gameObject.name == "SectionThree")
{

collision.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 0, section_placement);

}
else if (collision.gameObject.name == "SectionFour")
{

collision.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, 0, section_placement);

}

}
}
```

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong since setting `isKinematic` to true should've done the trick, the purpose of it is to prevent any form of physics, such as forces and collisions acting on a kinematic rigidbody and translation should still work. Don't set gameobjects to static unless they stay where they are at all times. Alternatively, if you don't want them to fall due to gravity, simply disable `useGravity` on the rigidbody?

Comment: In the rigidbody settings, simply freeze the rotation.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Collision can be tricky to master. You should reference the Collision Action Matrix on this page..

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

As you can see there, OnCollisionEnter will not be called for interaction between two kinematic bodies.  However OnTriggerEnter will, if you set your collider to be a trigger and kinematic.